# Why doesn't "need" take a "to" infinitive in some cases?

Tags: negation, bare-infinitive, semi-modals

In a book of Alexander McCall Smith I found this phrase:

> No historical novelists need apply.

Why isn't it this with a  *to* for the infinitive?

> No historical novelist need **to** apply?

Comment: It's a reference to a well-known idiom: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-Irish_sentiment#%22No_Irish_need_apply%22

Comment: @michael.hor257k It's not an idiom, just a modal use.

Comment: @tchrist I beg to differ. *No [group] need apply* is an idiom, and the quoted phrase makes use of it.

Comment: @michael.hor257k That question was asking about why we do not have a *to* with the infinitive following a negated *need*. That has nothing to do with your so-called ‘idiom’, which it is not. It has to do with actual grammar.

Comment: @tchrist The question is why does the author use this form. The answer is that he uses it because it's a well-known idiom. He would be well justified to use it, regardless of it being grammatical (which I am not entirely convinced of) or not.

Comment: @michael.hor257k The version he asked why didn't get used is ungrammatical, which is the point here. It is about grammar not meaning. The *to* becomes spurious.

Comment: @tchrist I thoroughly disagree that the "to" in "need to apply" is ungrammatical.

Comment: @WeatherVane Read the edit log: I did no such thing. The original was poorly formatted, and I merely improved this. He was always asking this.

Comment: @tchrist sorry yes I already deleted that part. But "I need to think" is perfectly good English, not "I need think".

Comment: @WeatherVane As for why *No historical novelist need to apply* turns out to be ungrammatical, that can be its own question if you can't figure it out from the master to which this is linked, or to those it links to.

Comment: @tchrist IMO the grammatical error is that "need" should be "needs". And note the typo in the question, "novelists" became "novelist" in the second version. Kept in the plural, "No historical novelists need to apply" is quite grammatical, but not idiomatic.

Answer (score 0):

It's a polite idiom used to tell them **not** to apply, because they are not wanted.

The phrase is often seen when a job vacancy is re-advertised after a suitable person was not found.

> Previous applicants need not apply.

Comment: This is not an idiom. It's modal *need*, which means it does not take a *to*-infinitive.

Comment: @tchrist by "idiom" I mean that the phrase indicates that historical novelists are not welcome, not that it is ungrammatical. As pointed out by michael.hor257k above.

Comment: Here are similar examples of modal *need*: *One need only apply..., One need never apply..., Need one apply...?* Those are all the base form of the verb, not the one inflected for number and person which would take a *to*-infinitive as in *One needs to apply oneself.*

Comment: @tchrist I understand that, but the sentence "No historical novelists need **to** apply" posted could be taken to mean they will be considered without applying, whereas the idiomatic use  "No historical novelists need apply" says they are unwelcome. Far from "need not" it means "must not". Do you know this usage?

Answer (score 0):

A variant is "need not apply," and as the previous poster said, it's an idiomatic expression that doesn't follow precisely the rules of English.

You should keep in mind that signs that people make are notoriously bad examples of proper English.

Comment: No, this is the wrong answer. It is not an idiom. The verb *need* is a semi-modal one, and in negative and interrogative contexts it can become a full modal: *He was content knowing that he need never apply to that school.*

Comment: +1 You are correct. It's both a regular sentence *and* an idiom. Generally speaking, in the *specific* sense of telling people to "go away" (which is a different meaning than just the words themselves), it's being used idiomatically.